# How to add custom header variable to the request and redirect the user

Tags: java, http, redirect, jakarta-ee

I am trying to build a Java EE application that extracts a certain session cookie, adds it to the request as an HTTP header then forwards the user to a 3rd party URL with this header variable in the request.

I am using [this example](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-modify-request-headers-in-a-j2ee-web-application/) as a reference.

I have implemented `FakeHeadersRequest` and `SimpleFilter` however not sure how to redirect the request to a different URL with this new header variable. Should I just create a Servlet that forwards the request? Perhaps use Apache http client?

Can someone please help me complete this puzzle?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are on the server side and have wrapped your request, use RequestDispatcher.forward() with that wrapped request.

The resource that you are forwarding to (any Servlet, JSP) will "see" the new header.

Do not attempt to redirect (HTTP 302) on the client side, it won't be easy to make the client send custom headers, AFAIK.

Comment: Hi, looks like RequestDispatcher is expecting a resource that is relative to my servlet location and I want to forward the request to a completely new URL. So RequestDispatcher doesn't seem to work in such a case. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: You may want to clarify whether you want the client to execute that 2nd request, or whether it's OK if your server does that request. For the latter case, Apache http client will be a good choice, and clearly you can tweak any and all headers with that approach. But it will then be your server that appears as the originator of the request towards that 3rd party server.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to redirect to a page with custom headers set, no matter what language or framework you use. In other words, there's no way to trigger an HTTP redirect and cause the client (browser) to add a custom header.

You're setting the custom headers for the response which is instructing the browser to redirect, not for the redirect itself.

The only way for a site to instruct a browser to issue an HTTP request with a custom header is to use Javascript and the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

The closest thing you could come up with is to act as a proxy. No redirection.